# Order results of an HTTP API

Tags: php, xml, matomo

Trying to find a way to reorder the result from an HTTP API. Here is an example

```
https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.get&idSite=7&period=month&date=last3&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous
```

which returns

```
<results>
   <result date="2017-10"/>
   <result date="2017-11"/>
   <result date="2017-12"/>
</results>
```

Yet, I want to it returned as

```
<results>
   <result date="2017-12"/>
   <result date="2017-11"/>
   <result date="2017-10"/>
</results>
```

I have tried using `filter_sort_order` in the URL but this didn't work. Is there a way to do this within the URL or a solution in `PHP` that can do this post getting the `XML`?

Comment: Are you writing the server code? Even if not, I am unsure why it is so difficult to sort the results in JS on the client side

Comment: is the API published anywhere?

Comment: No, I am not writing the server code. It is coming in from a self-hosted Piwik server as page analytics. I haven't tried sorting in JS as the API is pulled directly into the PHP as `$url = "` and results outputted as `print("$value");`

Comment: Then can you find the API documented anywhere/contact anyone to ask them?

Comment: Is it possible to do this within the PHP? According to Piwik https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api I should be able to sort by adding `&filter_sort_order=asc` to the API URL

Comment: Hasn't been possible to get support from them, was hoping there could be a clear solution that could be applied. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You already seem to have found some kind of API documentation, can you tell us where?

Comment: The documentation is https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continued from the comments:

Sorry, but if the API doenot provide an option, then you have to acecpt what it sends.

If you want the results to be sorted,  then you can either sort them client side in JavaScript, or fetch the data from your own server side PHP, sort them, and provide that as a an API to the client side.

If you want several different types of sorting, then I would suggest the latter.

Comment: The documentation here https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api does seem to support sorting but it won't work for me. I like your answer and I am pretty sure it has spurred me a solution.

Comment: There's always another way of looking at things:-) But, see my other answer. If the devs won't help, try asking oter users at the forum. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

One of the Piwik developers answered the following:

> Hi, it is expected that the reports are listed by date. Here the report has no dimension (only main metrics). A report with dimension is sorted but does sort each dataTable within a date… https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=7&period=month&date=last30&format=json&token_auth=anonymous&filter_sort_column=nb_visits&filter_sort_order=desc
>
> So basically the sorting is applied to data of each individual day and because VisitsSummary.get has no multiple rows, there is nothing sorted.
>
> Applying the sort filter to the dates for reports without a dimension won’t be a solution since we need consistent sorting behaviour for reports with and without a dimension. It would be a new feature to make this sortable and would need a new API parameter

(https://forum.piwik.org/t/filter-sort-order-not-working-on-visitssummary-get/26710/4)

Until this is a feature I'd recommend to sort the data client side.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, I came to a solution, simply by using `krsort($content);` of the fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your having already accepted my answer, now that you have published the [URL of the API](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api), I think that ***this*** is the correct answer:

> Optional API parameters
>
> Each API call can contain parameters that do not appear in the list of
>   parameters, but act as "filters". Filters can ... act as data
>   helpers (sort results...)."  .

A combination of these two would seem to be your answer

> filter_column ; defines the column that we want to search for a text
>   (see filter_pattern). If not specified, defaults to 'label'
>   .
>   filter_sort_order; defines the order of the results, asc or desc

If you can't figure it out, try contacting them via https://developer.piwik.org/support or asking other users at [the forum](https://forum.piwik.org/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time reading those things. I had followed their documentation but it hadn't worked for me. It may be something after the call that is preventing it. Your other answer best relates to understanding how what is needed and put me on the right track to learning the other options. I now have this sorted, no pun intended.

Comment: Loxl ! Plus one for having it sorted. Cheers